# Xamarin.Android - GC is stopping my app for 2 seconds

Tags: android, garbage-collection, xamarin

My application is generating huge GCs

```
GC_BRIDGE waiting for bridge processing to finish
GC_EXPLICIT freed 83K, 13% free 20422K/23303K, paused 3ms+6ms
GC_BRIDGE num-objects 8 num_hash_entries 192655 sccs size 182398 init 0.00ms df1 618.66ms sort 668.89ms dfs2 267.17ms setup-cb 92.16ms free-data 219.17ms user-cb 44.89ms clenanup 0.14ms links 15526347/15526347/159040609/136 dfs passes 28251143/27524490
GC_MINOR: (Nursery full) pause 643.96ms, total 644.45ms, bridge 1292.70ms promoted 0K major 33344K los 108818K
```

My app is using OpenGL, and runs using a GameLoop. I don't notice any big GC, until I use Android GUI.

I suspect that some of my code in Android GUI is badly written. 
I have read some very strange (and not-really-understandable) guidelines, like in [this documentation](http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/advanced_topics/garbage_collection/#Helping_the_GC) (see the HiddenReference part).

Of course I won't send here my entire source code. I just would like to learn how to investigate.

My question is :

Do the upper message give interesting/useful information? (how to read it)

How mean / how to understand GC_BRIDGE and GC_MINOR, and their values?

Answer (score 2):

All those informations are there to help you know what's going on with your app and its memory consumption.

It might not be a problem depending on what you are doing. For example, you will see the memory going up when you allocation high resolution Bitmaps. But there is a high chance that you have a memory leak in your application.

On Android it is harder to track them since the HeapShot tool doesn't exist (iOS with Xamarin Studio it is available). This tool help you track which object are retained in memory.

There is a way to double check on an activity basis if there is a leak or not. Put a GC.Collect() on a specific function that you can trigger easily in your application.

Once this is done, open the first activity (the main one) and notice the memory usage. Open another one go back to the previous one and trigger the GC.Collect. Notice the memory usage. Do the process multiple times and if the memory keep growing, there is a leak in your app.

---

There is a in depth description of most GC messages [on this website](https://sites.google.com/site/pyximanew/blog/androidunderstandingddmslogcatmemoryoutputmessages).

For the Nursery Full [read the Android Lead - Jonathan Pryor's answer](http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/35681/#Comment_35681).

You could also [read this thread about GC_Bridge](http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/12114/gc-bridge-takes-several-seconds-to-run-num-hash-entries-627215-and-causes-freezes) which I never saw myself in my app.

Answer (score -2):

I sugest to use `for(;;)` instead of `foreach()` whenever you are not sure if the enumerator generates garbage. Also, remove Linq. Best practice is to run a profiler every now and them to spot where you allocate new objects in your game loop.

You souldn't use the 'new' or any of the things above in the game loop. Instead pre-allocate everything in advance, use pooling , etc
The GC is triggered every 1MBytes of allocations or so and then you will see frame drops.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/shawnhar/archive/2007/07/02/twin-paths-to-garbage-collector-nirvana.aspx10

http://community.monogame.net/t/solved-fps-drops-ever-1-2-minutes/2446